# How to handle a docker swarm in secure way(when communication is using a public NIC)?

Tags: security, docker

I would connect 3 machines in a docker swarm using my unique and public NIC eth0.

Is the communication among the machines secure? 
For joining to a swarm i need a token , so i suppose at least there is a authentication control. But the channel for communication is encrypted? 
In addition i read i can add ecryption when i add a docker network. 
I suppose these channels are completely separated by control stream so they are 2 concept completely different.
I d like to receive a little clarification about how to secure swarm data&control streams

Comment: you should not be using an Internet facing NIC.

Comment: This is a trial answer sorry. In my case i cant

Answer (score 0):

Docker swarm controls streams encrypted by default. You can encrypt also data using network encryption.